# Registering observers in React Native native module on iOS (NSNotificationCenter)

Tags: ios, react-native, nsnotificationcenter

I have written a native module so as to bridge native iOS code (objective-c) with my react-native code. I'm trying to listen for events through NSNotificationCenter in the native module, but I'm not receiving any events. I'm setting up the listener in init in my module. I've included the code which listens for the events below. Unfortunately, it seems my methods are never run. Have I set it up wrong?

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(receivedData:)
                                                 name:ProtocolReceivedData
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(receivedEvent:)
                                                 name:ProtocolReceivedEvent
                                               object:nil];
    return self;
}

- (void)receivedData:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"%@", @"NATIVE MODULE HAS RECEIVED DATA");
}

- (void)receivedEvent:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"%@", @"NATIVE MODULE HAS AN EVENT");
}
```

Code which sends the notification looks like this,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ProtocolReceivedEvent
     object:self
     userInfo:userInfo];
```

Comment: Well. After a lot of faffing about, it turns out my methods were running as expected. However, NSLogs in my native module are not showing in the Xcode developer console.